# Adding alignment buttons to Trix Editor (ActionText Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alignment, trix, actiontext

I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/paramagicdev/modifying-the-default-toolbar-in-trix-411b) to add alignment options to Trix text editor and the editor in my app works similar to the [repository](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cb4oo7?file=style.css) referenced by the tutorial.
Meaning, clicking the align right button, will align text to the right, but when I save the form by clicking Submit button (my rich_text field is a part of the simple_form form), the text that I had previously aligned to the right, is now saved on the left (in its default position).
This is the text while being edited (before submit):

```
<align-right><strong>Hello</strong></align-right>
```

and this is the text after being saved:

```
<strong>Hello</strong>
```

Added

```
ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes += %w[ align-right align-center align-left ]
```

in config/initializers/action_text.rb
but it didn't make any difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your text is being sanitized by ActionText. Try

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'align-right'
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'align-center'
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'align-left'
end
```

in your *application.rb* file.